# Save data received from an observable(other componente svc) in a variable and fill out form

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I receive the data from another component with an observable (service), this data arrives fine. Why does it not save the data in a variable, nor does it load it to me in the form?

```
this.formactualizaruser = fb.group({
      nombre: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      hijos: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(60)]],
      admin: [],
    });
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listarDetalleActualizar();
  }

//
listarDetalleActualizar() {
    this.actuaUserSvc.getActualizarUserSvc().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.fillForm(data);
    });

fillForm(data: any) {
    this.datos = data
    console.log(this.datos) //I see the correct data in console {nombre: "ss", hijos:...
    this.formactualizaruser.patchValue({
      nombre: this.datos.nombre, 
      hijos: this.datos.hijos,
    });
  }

<form
[formGroup]="formactualizaruser">

 <input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="nombre"
  />
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are only setting the value and not any other formControl properties try using the `.setValue()` method instead:

```js
fillForm(data: any) {
    this.datos = data    
    this.formactualizaruser.get('nombre').setValue(this.datos.nombre);
    this.formactualizaruser.get('hijos').setValue(this.datos.nombre);     
  }
```